# Failed to get object property when it's stdClass object Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

So I tried to access object property but failed even when I checked it and it's object.

This is error message from CI4
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkGRW.png)

This is when I check it
[var_dump variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMpOC.png)

This is my code

```
<?php foreach($sell_wastes as $sw): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php $myWaste = $wastesModel->find($sw->waste_id) ?>
        <?php dd($myWaste) ?>
        <td><img src="<?= $myWaste->image_url ?>" width="100"></td>
        <td id="waste"><?= $sw->waste_name ?></td>
        <td> etc...
```

Comment: Error is self-explanatory. Read the documentation before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

It solved when I changed the result to array instead of object. I just don't know why the object results produce error like that.